# Как сделать перелистывание меню пальцем влево/вправо?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На [сайте](https://www.astrology-zodiac-signs.com/compatibility/aries/) есть меню второго уровня (синее), которое на мобильных листается пальцев влево/вправо. Как сделать такое меню?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для таких вопросов надо добавлять гифку или видео, а не ссылку(ведь мобильное меню работает только на мобильном)

Comment: *touchmove* вам не подходит?

Comment: Ничего космического нет в примере, это старый метод )) Через @media query  установите для блока фиксированную ширину а для родителя `owerflow` на авто + `nowrap`, вот и всё. Когда ширина экрана будет меньше ширины блока можно просто листать блок в право и в лево, на девайсах это простой scroll panel браузера, просто в мобильных браузерах он "не видим"

Comment: @Arsen, а чего не в ответ?

Comment: @qwabra можно конечно и пример показать, просто этот вопрос относится к разделу "дайте мысль, остальное сам смогу" :)  Если у автора не получится, могу показать пример.

Comment: @Arsen, а кто сказал что в ответах на вопрос вы ОБЯЗАНЫ приводить код? тем более, что сам автор этого не просит.

Comment: @Arsen в ответах не обязательно должен быть код. Главное - идея, которая поможет решить задачу поставленную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу вполне по силам решить чистым CSS без JavaScript.

> Да, шел 2020 год и скроллбары на винде скрываются именно так...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Drag and drop</title>
      <style>
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            background: transparent;
        }
        html {
            -ms-overflow-style: none;
            scrollbar-width: none;
        }
        nav {
          border: 1px solid black;
          overflow-x: scroll !important;
        }
        nav>ul {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          padding-inline-start: 0;
          margin-block-start: 0;
          margin-block-end: 0;
        }
        nav>ul>li {
          list-style-type: none;
          padding: 5px;
          margin: 5px;
        }
        nav>ul>li:not(:first-child) {
          margin-left: -1px;
          border-left: 1px solid black;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

P.S. Вы можете использовать следующий скрипт для скроллинга при удержании клавиши мыши на компьютерах

```
(function() {
  const element = document.querySelector('nav');
  let startX;
  let scrollLeft;
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', () => element.classList.remove('scrolling'));
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    element.classList.add('scrolling');
    startX = e.pageX - element.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;
  });
  const move = (x) => {
    if (!element.classList.contains('scrolling')) {
      return;
    }
    const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
    element.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  };
  element.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => move(e.pageX - element.offsetLeft));
})();
```

Comment: Да, всё верно, 2020 год уже. Вопрос, а зачем вы "прячете" скролбар для всех, в том числе и для десктопной версии сайта? вроде в вопросе спрашивали о мобильной версии, или я что то упустил? :)

Comment: @Arsen невнимательность) Ладно, по крайней мере, пример получился более объемный относительно сферы применения